# Remove "Move to Dropbox" menu from Finder context menu

Tags: finder, dropbox, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I want to remove the annoying "Move to Dropbox" entry in the context menu when I right click a file in macOS Finder.

I know I can disable Dropbox's Finder Extension all-together, but I do like the green check marks that display syncing status. I just don't want the clutter in the right-click context menu.

Is there a way to disable only this "Move to Dropbox" menu item while keeping Dropbox's other Finder integrations?

[image: Move to Dropbox Mac]

Comment: Untested, but it might be worth a try: https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-delete-the-annoying-move-to-dropbox-from-contextual-menus

Comment: Same question, but for the new "Send with Transfer..." menu item: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389415/remove-dropbox-send-with-transfer-item-from-finder-context-menu

Answer (score 17):

If you go to Preferences -> Extensions -> Finder, you will see the Finder extension that you can enable/disable and you can enable/disable the Finder extension from the Dropbox app itself.

Unfortunately I don't believe you can simply remove the one option but rather it's an all-or-nothing scenario based on the extension itself. Well, at least until Dropbox makes some improvements.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Only think I would add is that I had to "Force Close" Finder via Activity Monitor for this to take effect.

Comment: Ok, I spoke too soon. Dropbox re-enables that after some period of time, so the context item was back.

Comment: This no longer works, Dmitri Shuralyov's comment in AlexVPerl's answer below for the current method.

Answer (score 6):

Type (or copy and paste) this into a Terminal shell:

```sh
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox --move-to-dropbox=False
```

Comment: Mentioned here by a Dropbox community manager: [Dropbox Forum: How to permanently delete the 'Move to Dropbox' contextual menu item?](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-installs-integrations/Pleeeeease-does-anyone-know-how-to-permanently-delete-the-Move/td-p/13682)

Comment: do you known how to disable the `back up to dropbox` item?

Answer (score 6):

This now can be disabled at System Preferences > Extensions > Finder Extensions.

[image]

Comment: It also disables syncing status in the Dropbox folder. But the question was how to remove menu items only, while keeping green check marks

Answer (score 2):

Go into Dropbox Preferences and **uncheck "Finder Integration"**

[image]

Comment: They seem to have removed this option in more recent editions of Dropbox. I have v75.4.141 installed.

Comment: @orj They did remove it in v75.4.141 from Dropbox's Preferences. However, you can go to macOS System Preferences, Extensions, and uncheck "Dropbox Finder Integration" under "Finder Extensions" there.

Comment: @dmitri-shuralyov Ah, good point.

Answer (score -3):

This is called a "Finder Service"

http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/14/remove-services-contextual-menu-mac-os-x/

> **Removing Services from the Contextual Menus**
>
> To be clear, this removes items, but does not delete the service itself, meaning you can easily go back and re-enable them again should you decide to reverse this and want a service or two back again.
>
> 1. Locate the precise name of the service to remove by summoning the contextual menu from the Finder, in this example we’ll right-click a file and want to remove the “Make Contact Sheet” option from the menu list
> 2. Open System Preferences, found within the  Apple menu, and choose “Keyboard” from the preference panel options
> 3. Choose the “Keyboard Shortcuts” tab, then click on the “Services” option from the left sides options
> 4. Navigate through this list to find the exact name of the service you found in the first step, then uncheck the box next to it

Comment: No, this is not a service, it's an entry in the middle, not the bottom