# Remove Dropbox "Send with Transfer..." item from Finder context menu

Tags: macos, finder, dropbox, shortcut-menu

A recent version of Dropbox has added the new menu item "Send with Transfer..." when right-clicking *any file on your Mac*, not just files in Dropbox.

[image: Dropbox Send with Transfer...]

I know that Dropbox's Finder Extension can be disabled entirely. But this disables syncing badges and all Finder integration. I want to keep the Finder Extension enabled *for the Dropbox folder itself*... I just want to disable the global menu items when outside of the Dropbox.

The similar outside-the-folder "Move to Dropbox" menu item *can* be disabled individually:
[Remove “Move to Dropbox” menu from Finder context menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363128/1982)

[image: Hide Move to Dropbox menu item]

Is there a similar setting to hide the "Send with Transfer..." menu item individually?

Same question on the Dropbox forum:

> https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-installs-integrations/Remove-Dropbox-quot-Send-with-Transfer-quot-menu-item-from-macOS/m-p/545002

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Comment: I tried `/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox --send-with-transfer=False` but it doesn't work.. its annoying.

Comment: I tried deleting the helper installer TGZ and executable in /Library and the Dropbox package, but as of late 2021 it does not do the trick.