# Remove the dropbox options from the right click menu

Tags: finder, dropbox

When right clicked in the dropbox directory, the menu looks like this.

[image]

I don't use those dropbox options and don't plan on doing so in the future.  <s>I understand I can disable the dropbox extension for the Finder altogether and lose sync badges etc</s>, but is there a way to just disable these dropbox menu items?

Edit: Seems that if you disable the Finder extension, in Venture, it disables syncing altogether. *Chef's kiss.*

Comment: Related [Remove "Move to Dropbox" menu from Finder context menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/219659/37797) doesn't look promising for a solution here.

Comment: It also looks like that you can no longer turn off the finder extension, because that disables syncing as well.